# Como pegar retornar um boolean após um form.submit?

Tags: javascript, formulário, booleano, formulário-submeter

Eu tenho um formulario de cadastro de clientes que executa o submit no botão cadastrar:

```
document.getElementById("formularioCadastro").submit();
```

tudo ok, o cadastro funciona, mas eu queria retornar um BOOLEAN true ou false, para saber se foi cadastrado com sucesso ou deu erro.

tentei o seguinte codigo:

```
var sucess = document.getElementById("formularioCadastro").submit();

if(sucess == true){
    alert("cadastrado com sucesso!");
else{
    alert("erro ao cadastrar cliente");
    }
}
```

Porem não funcionou, alguem pode me ajudar?

Comment: Quando acontece a submissão do formulário, não é direcionado para a página definida em `action` do elemento `form`? Ou você está fazendo uma requisição assíncrona?

Comment: Pra saber se foi cadastrado com sucesso na verdade a resposta tem que vir do servidor, só pelo front não é possível dizer que foi "cadastrado" com sucesso.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss meu action chama um servlet, que cadastra o cliente, e quando o metodo acaba não sei se foi com sucesso ou com falha.

Comment: @LucasCosta, no meu servlet eu tenho o segunte trecho no fim do metodo: `request.setAttribute("sucess", "true");`

Comment: Uma dica seria fazer o submit sem atualizar a tela e chamar o servlet por ajax, fica mais sutil para o usuário e fazer o servlet retornar um http status: 500 para erro ou 200 para sucesso. Automaticamente cai no sucesso ou erro do ajax. No mais, é dificil reproduzir pra te ajudar com o que apresentou @20comer

Comment: @LucasCosta é simples assim mesmo igual voce está vendo, apenas isso mais nada. Não acho que precise utilizar AJAX para realizar essa tarefa, póis só preciso pegar o retorno de uma variavel do servlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode resolver isso utilizando o método `ajax` do [JQUERY](https://jquery.com/).

```
   $.ajax({

        type: 'POST',
        url : 'ServletName',//aqui você poe o nome do servlet
        async: false,
        data: { param1      :   value1,  //aqui
                param2      :   value2,  //vao
                param3      :   value3,  //os
                param4      :   value4}, //parametros

    success : function(){ //código da função caso sucesso

            alert("Sucesso");

                            },
    error: function(){ //código da função caso de erro

            alert("Falha!"); 

                         }
    );
```

Comment: Vou testar esse metodo, obrigado pelo comentario!